# Using broadcasting to multiply matrix rows according to elements in a vector?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a matrix

```
x=array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

I want to get

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  0.],
       [ 8.,  8.,  8.]])
```

How to write the one-line expression between `x` and `range(1,9)`? And what is the code for the same operation for columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x * np.arange(1, 9).reshape(-1, 1)
```

or

```
x * arange(1, 9)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Both forms make a column vector out of `arange(1, 9)`, which broadcasts nicely along the y axis of `x`.

"The same operation for columns" is just the transpose of the above, i.e. skip the `reshape` operation:

```
x * arange(1, 4)
```